# How can I remove specific elements from arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, search, filter

How can i remove an element that contains a specific letter from an array

```
function longest7SegmentWord(arr) {
///forbidden characters
var dellValue = ["k", "m", "v", "w" ,"x"]
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   for(var j=0; j<dellValue.length; j++){
     if (arr[i].indexOf(dellValue[j]) !==-1){
        console.log(arr[i])
        }
    }
  }
}

longest7SegmentWord(["knighthood", "parental", "fridge", "clingfilm", "k", "m", "v", "w"])
```

For example in this function the output should be

> "parental", "fridge"

I know that te problem is happening because the loop of "dellValue" keep returning the others deleted value, for example :

```
arr[i].indexOf(dellValue[0])
```

return every element without the "k" , but after when dellValue[1] is hit, return everything despite of "m" ecc...
is there other solutions, even using RegEx, such us search() / filter ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function longest7SegmentWord(arr) {
  ///forbidden characters
  var dellValue = ["k", "m", "v", "w", "x"]
  return arr.filter((value) => !dellValue.some(del => value.includes(del)))
}

const res = longest7SegmentWord(["knighthood", "parental", "fridge", "clingfilm", "k", "m", "v", "w"]);
console.log(res)
```